# Why doesn't php behave the same as when I explicitly set a value?

Tags: php, string, drupal, date

I have tried the same code both ways, it works the first way, when I do it the second way, it doesn't error, but just appears to do nothing.

I'm getting some values (two dates) in a View in Drupal. I can print the values and get EXACTLY the same values as I have set explicitly. I've tested this using print.

Although the values using print are identical to those i've set explicitly, it's not working with the data pulled from Drupal.

Example of printing:

```
$fields['field_deal_from_value']->content;

//The result from this is that it prints the following:

2011-04-24
```

**Version 1 - Working with explicitly set value**

```
<?php
$pastDateStr = "2011-04-24"; 
$pastDateTS = strtotime($pastDateStr); 

for ($currentDateTS = $pastDateTS; $currentDateTS <= strtotime("2011-05-28");$currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) { 
// use date() and $currentDateTS to format the dates in between 
$currentDateStr=date("d-m-Y",$currentDateTS); 
print $currentDateStr."<br/>"; 
}
?>
```

**Version 2 - Not Working - Values are definitely set correctly**

```
<?php
$pastDateStr = $fields['field_deal_from_value']->content; 
$pastDateTS = strtotime($pastDateStr); 

for ($currentDateTS = $pastDateTS; $currentDateTS <= strtotime($fields['field_deal_to_value']->content); $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) { 
// use date() and $currentDateTS to format the dates in between 
$currentDateStr=date("d-m-Y",$currentDateTS); 
print $currentDateStr."<br/>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `print_r` or `var_dump` for debugging.

Comment: Try checking the value of `$fields['field_deal_to_value']->content` as well.

Comment: What happens when you use print_r($fields['field_deal_from_value']->content) and print_r($fields['field_deal_to_value']->content)? Did you try to use PHP's DateTime class for date manipulation?

Comment: This looks like an anti-pattern of a for loop. Break that stuff out, or it will be a pain in the future when you come back to it.

Comment: When I use the two print_r statements it just prints out the two dates correctly, as i'd expect them to

Comment: @Christian I have checked the value of both, but only included one as an example to show i've checked the values. To me this should be working, and if it isn't then it should be throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn error reporting all the way so you can see warnings.
I suspect you'll see an error saying that the result of $fields['..']->content cannot be used in a write context (ie as the argument of strtotime).
I'd try to save the value of $fields['..']->content in a variable and use that variable in the loop's condition.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
<?php


$pastDateStr = "2011-04-24";
$pastDateTS = strtotime($pastDateStr);

for ($currentDateTS = $pastDateTS; $currentDateTS <= strtotime("2011-05-28");            $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
// use date() and $currentDateTS to format the dates in between
    $currentDateStr=date("d-m-Y",$currentDateTS);
    print $currentDateStr."<br/>";
}


var_dump("break");

class X {
    var $content = "2011-04-24";
}
class Y {
    var $content = "2011-05-28";
}
$fields['field_deal_from_value'] = new X();
$fields['field_deal_to_value'] = new Y();



$pastDateStr = $fields['field_deal_from_value']->content;
$pastDateTS = strtotime($pastDateStr);

for ($currentDateTS = $pastDateTS; $currentDateTS <= strtotime($fields['field_deal_to_value']->content); $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
// use date() and $currentDateTS to format the dates in between
    $currentDateStr=date("d-m-Y",$currentDateTS);
    print $currentDateStr."<br/>";
}


?>
```

works fine because i've set the $fields['field_deal_to_value']!

Comment: The value is already set as i'm getting the data from a View in Drupal 6. I need to pickup the value output by Drupal (Which does output the correct dates) and then use those. So setting the value myself won't achieve what i'm looking to do.

Comment: no i just wanted to show that by setting these values by hand, this code worcs perfectly. So the problem must be somewhere in your $fields array or in the ->content. try var_dump($fields) and var_dump($fields['field_deal_from_value']->content,$fields['field_deal_to_value']->content)

Comment: Thanks i'll try this later this afternoon. Not sure why it isn't working. I might just grab the values again from the database, it will be an extra call but there isn't much going on in the page anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo or logic error. If you replace this line

```
for ($currentDateTS = $pastDateTS; $currentDateTS <= strtotime($fields['field_deal_to_value']->content); $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
```

with

```
for ($currentDateTS = $pastDateTS; $currentDateTS <= strtotime("2011-05-28"); $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
```

then you'll get the same output. The difference is what you're comparing in the for loop.

In your code the second sample is essentially only asking it to iterate once while the first iterates several times.

Comment: I don't really get it. What's the difference between those two lines when fed with correct data?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting up XDebug and stepping through the code so that you can see exactly what's happening. It works fine with many of the common IDEs (NetBeans, Eclipse, etc.)